# How to store images into cassandra database using cql-engine?

Tags: django, image, django-models, cassandra, cql3

I'm using **python** and **django framework**! How to store **images** into **Cassandra** database using **cql engine**? And how can i **display** this images in an image_tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move binary data in and out of cassandra with cqlengine, you'll want to use the Bytes column.

To expose the image via an `<image/>` tag, you'll probably want to setup a view that returns the saved binary data, and set the mimetype on the django response.